# Match every thing between "****" or [****]

Tags: regex

I have a regex that look [like this](https://regex101.com/r/SiZiIp/1):

```
(?="(test)"\s*:\s*(".*?"|\[.*?]))
```

to match the value between `"..."` or `[...]`

Input

```
"test":"value0"
"test":["value1", "value2"]
```

Output

```
Group1     Group2
test       value0
test       "value1", "value2" // or - value1", "value2
```

I there any trick to ignore `""` and `[]` and stick with two group, `group1` and `group2`?

I tried `(?="(test)"\s*:\s*(?="(.*?)"|\[(.*?)]))` but this gives me 4 groups, which is not good for me.

Comment: Could you maybe provide some sample input and expected output? It's though to understand what you're trying to do

Comment: I edit my question @Dominik

Comment: Yes, `"(test)"\s*:\s*(?|"([^"]*)"|\[([^]]*)])`. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SiZiIp/2).

Comment: This is nice @WiktorStribiżew :), is there any way to use Lookahead to igniore unused parts ?

Comment: Like `"test"\s*:\s*\K(?:"\K[^"]*|\[\K[^]]*)`? See https://regex101.com/r/SiZiIp/3 Sorry, which parts are "unused"?

Comment: Yes like this `"(test)"\s*:\s*\K(?:"\K[^"]*|\[\K[^]]*)`, you can put your comment as answer I will accept it

Comment: Ok, but note that the full match will be the value and the Group 1 value will be the `test` (key).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ah I'm sorry I don't see it correctly, In fact I want to get the full match as group 2, is this possible ?

Comment: :) That was my first suggestion

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes your first solution was fine, thank you any way ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229574/discussion-between-ycf-l-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a pattern like

```php
"(test)"\s*:\s*\K(?|"\K([^"]*)|\[\K([^]]*))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SiZiIp/5).

*Details*:

- `"` - a `"` char
- `(test)` - Group 1: `test` word
- `"` - a `"` char
- `\s*:\s*` - a colon enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
- `\K` - match reset operator that clears the current overall match memory buffer  (group value is still kept intact)
- `(?|"\K([^"]*)|\[\K([^]]*))` - a [**branch reset group**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html):

  - `"\K([^"]*)` - matches a `"`, then discards it, and then **captures into Group 2** zero or more chars other than `"`
  - `|` - or
  - `\[\K([^]]*)` - matches a `[`, then discards it, and then captures into Group 2 zero or more chars other than `]`

In Java, you can't use `\K` and `?|`, use capturing groups:

```java
String s = "\"test\":[\"value1\", \"value2\"]";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"(test)\"\\s*:\\s*(?:\"([^\"]*)|\\[([^\\]]*))");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println("Key: " + matcher.group(1)); 
    if (matcher.group(2) != null) {
        System.out.println("Value: " + matcher.group(2)); 
    } else {
        System.out.println("Value: " + matcher.group(3)); 
    }
}
```

See a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/TyZtca).

Comment: @YCF_L I added the Java demo.

Answer (score 6):

You may use this conditional regex in PHP with **branch reset group**:

```sh
"(test)"\h*:\h*(?|"([^"]*)"|\[([^]]*)])
```

**This will give you 2 capture groups** in both the inputs with enclosing `"` or `[...]`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ilt3Wl/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?|..)` is a **branch reset group**. Here Subpatterns declared within each alternative of this construct will start over from the same index
- `(?|"([^"]*)"|\[([^]]*)])` is `if-then-else` conditional subpatern which means if `"` is matched then use `"([^"]*)"` otherwise use `\[([^]]*)]` subpattern

Comment: I am well aware of these techniques to build a regex. I didn't check series of comments below question earlier.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew and anubhava If you don't mind, `(?|` Branch reset group. is there an equivalent in Java, I tried your solutions in Java but I god an exception ?

Comment: @YCF_L No, there is not. Stick to groups without any `\K` or `(?|`.

Comment: @YCF_L: Java doesn't even support conditional construct in regex