# How to ignore some symbols in a regex with named capture groups

Tags: regex, regex-group

Suppose that we have a regex with a named capture group like this:

```
^(?<my_group>00[A-Za-z]{1}|0[A-Za-z]{2}|[A-Za-z]{3})$
```

In this case, "my_group" will contain either 00x or 0xx or xxx.

Now I want to store only "x-es" in it, so "my_group" should contain x/xx/xxx. But I cannot figure out how to achieve this behavior.

The only thing that kinda worked out was creating a separate "inner" named groups:

```
^(?:00(?<my_group1>[A-Za-z]{1})|0(?<my_group2>[A-Za-z]{2})|(?<my_group3>[A-Za-z]{3}))$
```

But in this case, I'm forced to use different group names because it's forbidden to use the same name in majority of the programming languages (but it could be ok since I use `|` between them, and at most one of these parts can be matched).

How can it be solved? Note that I cannot throw "zeros" away since this regex is used for string matching before splitting to the groups (so only 00x/0xx/xxx can be passed initially).

Comment: Use a [branch reset group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html): `^(?|00([A-Za-z])|0([A-Za-z]{2})|([A-Za-z]{3}))$`, see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0uFrTq/1).

Comment: Damn, seems like it's not supported in Java (initially, I thought that the language doesn't matter so I didn't stated it in the question). Maybe you know some workarounds or different solutions for this? At the same time, this approach is technically correct, so feel free to post it as an answer, and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66495002/3832970) is an example workaround. Probaby, you can modify the pattern you are using so that zeros appear outside the group.

Comment: Try `text.matches("(?=.{3}$)0{0,2}(?<mygroup>[A-Za-z]{1,3})")`, see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0uFrTq/2).

Comment: Is it possible to use this approach for strings like "00x0xx" where you have multiple similar blocks without any separators (in this particular case, you need to get mygroup1=00x and mygroup2=0xx with a "doubled" regex)? Seems that using anchors or custom start/end symbols in a lookahead block is crucial here. With the original approach from the question it's much easier

Comment: It looks like some extra requirement, your question is about matching a whole string. Does it mean the suggestion works for the question and can be posted as an answer?

Comment: Yeah, sure, your last suggestion works well for the particular case from the question, thank you for your effort

Comment: I will post that as an answer then, and please note it is not possible to do without enumeration of alternatives in other cases, because it is not the boundaries here that make it work, but the lookahead that requires the string to only contain 3 chars. Changing the boundaries does not work as the consuming part will still match as many chars as necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```java
text.matches("(?=.{3}$)0{0,2}(?<mygroup>[A-Za-z]{1,3})")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0uFrTq/2).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string (implicit in `String#matches`)
- `(?=.{3}$)` - a positive lookahead that requires the string to contain only 3 chars
- `0{0,2}` - zero to two `0` chars
- `(?<mygroup>[A-Za-z]{1,3})` - Group "mygroup": one to three letters
- `$` - end of string (implicit in `String#matches`).